# Infinite Groups with Finitely many Conjugacy Classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

> If $G$ is an infinite group with finitely many conjugacy classes, what can be said about $G$?  (Should $G$ be simple/ solvable/....?) For $n\geq 2$, does there exists a (infinite) group $G$ with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes, which is periodic also?

I couldn't find any information on these questions. One may provide links also for details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, since any torsion free group can be embedded in a group with only two conjugation classes (this imo is astonishing. It follows from the HNN extension theorems), we already see that not much can be said...

Comment: @DonAntonio I never knew that.  [Neat!](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/88997/92067)

Comment: For you second question, consider the group $Z/nZ$.

Comment: @studious: this is correct; but I had mistake in question; the groups I was expecting were **infinite**.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, you can read about the HNN extensions in the books by Rotman and by Robinson. The former also brings some topological applications, with van Kampen and stuff. Very interesting.