# Homogeneous groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let's call a group $G$ *homogeneous* if for every two distinct, non-identity elements $a$ and $b$ there is an automorphism $\phi$ of $G$ such that $\phi(a)=b$.

Examining this definition, we can see that the underlying additive group of any field (indeed, any division ring) is homogeneous by examining the automorphism $\phi(x)=ba^{-1}x$.

Thus for any $n$ and any prime $p$, we have that $Z_p^n$ is homogeneous. Conversely, if we also know that $G$ is finite, we can show that $G$ is of the form $Z_p^n$ for some $n$ and $p$.

> We can clearly see that all elements of a homogeneous group have the same order. And by Cauchy's theorem, we get that $G$ must have prime-power order. Say $|G|=p^n$. The Conjugacy Class Equation then implies that $G$ has non-trivial center. And since $G$ is homogeneous, all elements are in the center and thus $G$ is abelian. Since $G$ is finite, abelian, and all elements have the same order, we can conclude that $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_p^n$. If it weren't the fundamental theorem of abelian groups would imply there were an element of order $p^i$ for $i>1$ contradicting the fact that all elements have the same order (Cauchy's theorem still implies there's an element of order $p$).

Thus finite, homogeneous groups are kind of boring. Infinite examples are more interesting as we can garner a couple examples just from fields, and they are more difficult to investigate. We can still surmise a couple things when $G$ is infinite. For example, if $G$ has a single non-identity element of finite order then all (non-identity) elements of $G$ have prime order.

> Let $x\neq e$ have finite order $n$. Let $n=p^em$ for some prime $p$ with $e\geq 1$ and $p\nmid m$. Then the element $x^{p^{e-1}m}$ has order $p$, and thus all elements have order $p$.

Also, in general,

- If $G$ has a non-trivial center then it is abelian.
- Any quotient by a characteristic subgroup is also homogeneous.

I am having difficulty figuring out other, even basic, things though. My question is kind of general:

> **What else can we determine about homogeneous groups?**

I am specifically interested in these questions:

- <strike>Does $G$ have to be abelian?</strike>
- <strike>If not, can $G$ be perfect?</strike>
- Can $G$ be free? It clearly can't have rank 1, but what about other ranks?
- If all elements have prime order, is $G$ a direct sum of multiple copies of $Z_p$?

But any addition is welcome and appreciated.

**-UPDATE**

Qiaochu Yuan has deftly answered three of my original questions, but one still remains though it may be difficult. However his answer has left me intrigued for a proof of the following claim:

- Every abelian, homogenous group is the underlying additive group of some field.

I don't see how you could construct the multiplication operation, but it seems the choice for which element would become unity is a free choice.

Comment: $G$ can't be free. An automorphism-invariant property that distinguishes some elements of a (nonabelian) free group from others is that some of them lie in the commutator subgroup and others don't. (More generally, a homogeneous group can't have any nontrivial characteristic subgroups. In fact it can't have any nontrivial characteristic subsets, since by definition the action of the automorphism group on non-identity elements is transitive.)

Comment: The examples you get from division rings are not that diverse; as groups, they are all vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. I don't know if there are other examples. Also, the comment above shows that questions 1 and 2 are equivalent: if $G$ is not abelian then it must be perfect.

Comment: As for the question in the edit, once you have the last result in my answer that every such group is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ then the problem reduces to showing that field extensions of the former and the latter can have every possible dimension. This is straightforward in the finite-dimensional case and the infinite-dimensional case should be handleable by adjoining an appropriate number of variables, although the details seem annoying.

Comment: You should post the edited question as a new question, and link back to this one. You will be more likely to get an answer this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. $G$ does not have to be abelian. There exist examples of infinite (necessarily highly nonabelian) [groups with exactly two conjugacy classes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88980/infinite-group-with-only-two-conjugacy-classes); that is, even the action of inner automorphisms on non-identity elements is transitive.
2. As observed in the comments, since $[G, G]$ is a characteristic subgroup, if $G$ is nonabelian then it is necessarily perfect.
3. As observed in the comments, nonabelian free groups are not perfect.

I don't know the answer to the last question. It seems potentially difficult due to the existence of [Tarski monsters](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tarski_monster).

[Groupprops claims](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_whose_automorphism_group_is_transitive_on_non-identity_elements) that for abelian groups this property is equivalent to being the underlying [additive group of a field](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Additive_group_of_a_field), although I don't immediately see a proof. As observed in the comments, as groups these are just vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Edit:** Here's a proof that if $G$ is abelian then it's a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ or $\mathbb{Q}$. As you observed, if $G$ has an element of finite order then every element has order $p$ for some prime $p$, hence $G$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space. Otherwise, every element has infinite order. If $g \in G$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then by assumption there is an automorphism $\varphi : G \to G$ such that $\varphi(ng) = n \varphi(g) = g$. Hence $G$ is divisible, and an abelian torsion-free divisible group is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [this](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~ould/Fiches-papiers/homogeneity-prime.pdf) paper. The author proves that, in a certain sense, free groups of finite rank *are* homogeneous. The "certain sense" is, loosely, that if $a$ and $b$ satisfy the same formulae then they are connected by an automorphism.