# Homology of free loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, loop-spaces

By rational homotopy theory, $H(\Lambda M; \mathbb{Q})$ is infinite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$ if $M$ is simply-connected. Are there (non-simply-connected) examples when $H(\Lambda M; \mathbb{Q})$ is finite-dimensional? I am most interested when $M$ is a manifold. Also, note that 
$H_0(\Lambda M; \mathbb{Q})$ is the set of conjugacy classes of $\pi_1(M)$, ie. loops up to homotopy.

Comment: Your title says "based loop space", but usually $\Lambda M$ is the space of *free* loops (i.e. unbased). Which is it...?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks for pointing this out. It should be free loop space; I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a nontrivial (say, infinite) group $G$ which has exactly two conjugacy classes (e.g. one given by the HNN construction). Now, take $X=K(G,1)$. By working harder one can construct examples of such groups which have finite cohomological dimension and, hence, are fundamental groups of (noncompact) aspherical manifolds.

Edit. In fact, if you apply the  [HNN construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88980/infinite-group-with-only-two-conjugacy-classes) to the infinite cyclic group $G_0$, the result will an (infinitely generated) countable group $G$ of cohomological dimension 2 with exactly two conjugacy classes (the presentation complex $X$ of $G$ will be 2-dimensional and aspherical). Hence, by Stallings embedding theorem, there exists a 4-dimensional aspherical manifold $M=K(G,1)$ (obtained by embedding $X'$ homotopy-equivalent to $X$ into $R^4$ and then taking a regular neighborhood there).

Lastly, there are no known examples of infinite finitely presented groups with finitely many conjugacy classes.

Comment: Do you have examples of closed (compact) manifolds with the property tha $H(\Lambda M)$ is finite-dimensional? In this case, $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely-generated.

Comment: @user39598: As far as I know, there are no known examples of infinite finitely presented groups with finitely many conjugacy classes. Finitely generated examples were only relatively recently constructed by Osin (Annals of Math. 2010).

Comment: I looked at the Osin article but I'm not sure that it applies to manifolds. I am interested in a closed manifold such that $H(\Lambda M)$ is finite-dimensional. One potential example is when $M$ is hyperbolic  and $\pi_1(M)$ has finitely many conjugacy classes (but $\pi_1(M)$ is itself infinite). The examples from Osin are finitely-generated groups with finitely many conjugacy classes but I'm not sure that these groups are the fundamental groups of closed hyperbolic manifolds - for example, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is not since it is not infinite.

Comment: @user39598 Infinite hyperbolic groups have infinitely many conjugacy classes. To get a compact manifold one needs a finitely presented group, but such infinite groups are unknown.

Comment: @MoiseCohen Thank you. So just to clarify, is my question still unknown? Whether there are closed manifold such that $H(\Lambda M)$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: @user39598: If you assume that the manifold is connected with infinite fundamental group then yes, unknown.

Comment: I don't understand these two sentences in your reply: "If $\pi_1(M)$ is finite then $H_∗(\Lambda M;\mathbb{Q})$ will be finite dimensional since it embeds in the rational cohomology ring of the free loop space of the universal cover of M." This is false since if M is simply-connected, then $H_∗(\Lambda M;\mathbb{Q})$  is always infinite-dimensional. Also you say " Lastly, there are no known examples of finitely presented groups with finitely many conjugacy classes." What about any abelian group? I think you mean, infinite groups that are finitely presented.