# Effect of conjugacy on isomorphisim

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If in a group there are only two conjugacy classes then group is isomorphic  to Z2 . This statement is true or not ?

Comment: Hint for finite groups: cardinality of conjugacy class divides order of group.

Comment: The simple answer is no, it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the statement is true for finite groups!!

First observe that for $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ the statement is correct. Now for any group $G$ let us assume it has only 2 conjugacy classes. Now the identity element $\{\ e \}\ $ has its own singleton class. Hence the other remaining class contains $|G|-1$ number of elements. But the size of conjugacy class divides the order of the group, hence  $|G|-1 | |G|$. What is the only possibility for $|G|$ in this case ; |G|=2 is the only possible one. Hence the result.

Comment: How about infinite groups then? The statement is not true. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88980/75923).

Comment: Yeah thanks!!! I assumed he was only asking about finite groups..  Although I didn't knew about infinite groups!!