# Isomorphic two abelian subgroups which lies in the some finite union of conjugacy classes of simple group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a simple group and $H_1$ and $H_2$ be abelian subgroups of $G$ such that $H_1\cong H_2$ and $H_1,H_2\subseteq Cl_G(e_G)\cup Cl_G(x)$ for some $x\in G$, where $Cl_G(\cdot)$ denotes the conjugacy class on $G$.

Is it true that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are conjugate subgroups in $G?$
That is, is there is an element $g\in G$ so that $g^{-1}H_1g=H_2?$

Is it true that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are finitely generated abelian subgroups?

Comment: There are finite counterexamples

Comment: @DerekHolt such as?

Comment: The question is very good. Why close it?
I think there is a counterexample for infinitely generated groups.  Consider the group $G=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$. It has a continuum $\Delta$ pairwise isomorphic subgroups. We embed $G$ in a countable group $G^*$ in which any two nontrivial elements are conjugate (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88980)). It is clear that there are two non-conjugate subgroups of $\Delta$.

Comment: @kabenyuk As I said, three are finite counterexamples but I am trying to maintain the conventions of the site by not answering questions completely lacking in context.

Comment: Derek Holt, I agree with you that there is no context. But there are many such questions here. For example, the question I referred to. It's two lines. @pharazphazel please provide some context, such as how this problem arose and how you tried to solve it. In a nutshell.

Comment: Is $e_G$ the identity element of $G$? If yes, the question is obviously true.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki As I keep saying, there are finite counterexamples.

Comment: Ah right, now I see it. Thanks.

Comment: Also the final sentence of the post doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3):

As Derek indicated, there are counterexamples. Take $G=SL(2,16)$ and $x$ an involution. Then your union contains a full Sylow $2$-subgroup $P$, which is elementary abelian. Subgroups of $P$ are conjugate in $G$ if and only if they are conjugate in $N_G(P)$ by a theorem of Burnside. But there are too many subgroups of order $4$ to form a single conjugacy class (use the Gaussian binomial coefficient to compute their number).

Comment: Yes that's exactly the example I had in mind. You get similar examples in ${\rm PGL}(2,p^n)$ for prime $p$ and large enough $n$.